# Uploading images from Angular 8 and NativeScript to Rails ActiveStorage

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, angular, nativescript, rails-activestorage

I've got a NativeScript 6.0 mobile app with Angular 8.x with a Rails 5.2.x backend and I'm trying to upload a picture taken with the camera on the mobile (Android) to the backend using ActiveStorage.

I have setup and tested sending an image through the Rails backend using the Rails views and this works fine, so I know the backend is setup correctly. I also have my mobile app sending form data to the Rails backend without a problem using the standard http plugin for Angular.

I'm using the npm activestorage package to try and get Angular to talk to the Rails backend to send the image. I have a button in my mobile app which allows me to take a picture and after it's taken that picture I want to send it to the backend.

Here is the method which is ran when taking a picture;

```
onTakePictureTap(args) {
    requestPermissions().then(
        () => {
            var imageModule = require("tns-core-modules/ui/image");

            takePicture({width: 150, height: 100, keepAspectRatio: true})
                .then((imageAsset: any) => {
                    this.cameraImage = imageAsset;

                    let image = new imageModule.Image();
                    image.src = imageAsset;

                    // Get the file URL
                    this._dataItem.picture_url = this.imageAssetURL(imageAsset);

                    // Upload the file to ActiveStorage on the Rails 5.x backend
                    this.uploadFile(image);

                }, (error) => {
                    console.log("Error: " + error);
                });
        },
        () => alert('permissions rejected')
    );
} // onTakePictureTap
```

Here is the uploadFile method;

```
uploadFile(file) {
    // The URL is where the file will be stored on the backend.
    const url = "http://192.168.1.4:9000/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads";

    const upload = new DirectUpload(file, url);

    // // This upload create returns a hash with an id which has to be saved on the model.
    // // The signed_id is the one to look out for and save.

    // upload.create((error, blob) => {
    //     if (error) {
    //         // Handle the error
    //     } else {
    //         // Add an appropriately-named hidden input to the form with a
    //         //  value of blob.signed_id so that the blob ids will be
    //         //  transmitted in the normal upload flow
    //         const hiddenField = document.createElement('input')
    //         hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    //         hiddenField.setAttribute("value", blob.signed_id);
    //         hiddenField.name = input.name
    //         document.querySelector('form').appendChild(hiddenField)
    //     }
    // })
}
```

The error I'm currently getting is;

```
LOG from device Galaxy S8: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: activestorage__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10__.DirectUpload is not a constructor
LOG from device Galaxy S8: TypeError: activestorage__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10__.DirectUpload is not a constructor
LOG from device Galaxy S8: at HomeComponent.webpackHotUpdate../app/home/home.component.ts.HomeComponent.uploadFile (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/0.caccc158b823887c3ace.hot-update.js:217:22)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: at file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/0.caccc158b823887c3ace.hot-update.js:249:23
LOG from device Galaxy S8: at ZoneDelegate.invoke (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:388:18)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: at Object.onInvoke (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:24394:27)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: at ZoneDelegate.invoke (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:387:24)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: at Zone.run (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/...
```

How do I use activestorage properly in Angular to send a picture to the backend?

Comment: Where does `DirectUpload` come from? Note: You can not use browser specific packages in NativeScript, if you are looking to upload multi-part data to remote server, you must use [nativescript-background-http](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-background-http/) plugin.

Comment: @Manoj DirectUpload comes from a npm package called activestorage and they say it can be used in JS frameworks. I take your point though and will start using nativescript-background-http instead and a more flexible backend like the Shrine gem

Comment: For instance Angular is browser based framework, `nativescript-angular` injects some hooks to make it work with {N}, mimics XHR client to support HttpClient etc., Whichever NPM package or JavaScript library you use should be independent of browser features. For example, if it uses Blob for multi part request it won't work for {N}.